# How to add charging to LED light running on 2s 18650?

Tags: led, battery-charging, 18650

I am new at this and was hoping for some guidance.

I currently have this setup for testing-

2s 18650 7.4V --> Constant Current Boost Regulator (XY-SJVA-4) --> 20W LED

I can't seem to find clear information regarding adding the ability to recharge via USBC as I have two 18650 running in series.

Is something like the attached photo suitable? It seems to vary from the tp4056 as it doesn't have load terminals.

[image: charger module product picture]
<sub>Product photo from: [AliExpress - Module Sky shop, "Type-C BMS 2S 3S 4S 1A 2A 4A 18650 Lithium Battery Charger Board With Terminal Step-up Boost Module For Li-Po Polymer Power Bank"](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004536944540.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.35.53101802mQS7sq)</sub>

Can I do this?

[image: wiring diagram]

Any advice would be much appreciated.